# ansible regexp grabbing target machine ip address

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to grab ip address and fqdn of the target machine and add it in /etc/hosts of local machine using Ansible playbook. I have written the below playbook but I'm not able to add only fqdn and ip, other content is also getting added. Thanks in advance.

The expected format in /etc/hosts file of the local machine

```
localserver.example.com x.x.x.x
```

The current format in /etc/hosts file of the local machine

> {'failed': False, 'changed': False, 'ansible_facts': {u'target_ip': u'x.x.x.x'}} localserver.example.com

**Ansible playbook**

```yaml
- name: register target ip
  set_fact:
    target_ip: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
  register: target_ip
  
- debug:
    var: target_ip
  
- name: Getting fqdn of host
  shell: hostname
  register: fqdn
 
- name: Removing existing host entry from /etc/hosts before adding new
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/hosts
    regexp: '^{{ target_ip }}'
    state: absent
 
- name: Adding fqdn value to /etc/hosts of TVM
  lineinfile:
    path: /etc/hosts
    regexp: '(^\s+{{ target_ip }}([\w=/\-\.\,\_]+)*)\s*$'
    line: "{{ target_ip }} {{ fqdn.stdout }}"
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The playbook below does the job

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_01
  tasks:
    - name: FreeBSD register target ip
      set_fact:
        target_ip: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses']|first }}"
      when: ansible_os_family == 'FreeBSD'
    - name: Other OS register target ip
      set_fact:
        target_ip: "{{ hostvars[inventory_hostname]['ansible_default_ipv4']['address'] }}"
      when: ansible_os_family != 'FreeBSD'
    - debug:
        var: target_ip
  
    - name: Getting fqdn of host
      shell: hostname
      register: fqdn
    - debug:
        var: fqdn.stdout
 
    - name: Adding fqdn value to /etc/hosts of TVM
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/hosts.test
        regexp: '^\s*{{ target_ip }}(.*)$'
        line: "{{ target_ip }} {{ fqdn.stdout }}"
      delegate_to: localhost
      become: true
```

```sh
shell> cat /etc/hosts.test
10.1.0.51 test_01.example.org
```

Notes

- Do not register the variable in *set_fact*. I've changed the attributes for FreeBSD. There might be differences in data collected by setup on various systems. The task gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ****
ok: [test_01] => 
  target_ip: 10.1.0.51
```

- There is no reason to remove the line when you add or change it in the next task. I've removed this task completely.
- The module *lineinfile* is idempotent when the regexp matches the line before and after the module was executed. There is no reason to specify the rest of the line after *target_ip*.

---

Optionally, add the hostname alias

```yaml
        line: "{{ target_ip }}
               {{ fqdn.stdout }}
               {{ fqdn.stdout.split('.')|first }}"
```

gives

```sh
shell> cat /etc/hosts.test
10.1.0.51 test_01.g2.netng.org test_01
```